# pairing data between two files

Tags: python

I'm trying to match data between two files.

File 1:

```
# number of records, name
1234, keyword
```

File 2:

```
# date/time, name
2016-10-13| here is keyword in the name
```

as a result, I'd like to have File 3 written as:

```
# number of records, name, date
1234, here is keyword in the name, 2016-10-13
```

So the idea here is to iterate through File 1, get all keywords and check File 2 if it exists there. If that's true, take first field (date) from File 2 and put is as last item in File 1. I wrote following code to test few things but it's not working well. First issue I have is that python is not finding any `keyword` in File 2.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv

FILE1='file1'
FILE2='file2'

file2data=[]
with open(FILE2, 'rb') as file2file:
    reader = csv.reader(file2file, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        file2data.append(row)

def check(name):
    print('checking: "%s"' % name)
    rval=[]
    for item in file2data:
        if name in item:
            rval.append(item)
    return rval

with open(FILE1, 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in csvreader:
        entries=row[0]
        keyword=row[1].strip()
        checked=check(keyword)
        if checked:
            print('ok')
```

Anyone know why is that happening? Why inside `check()` function the following code

```
if name in item:
```

is not finding any values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this

```
if name in item:
```

checks if there is an item *cell* with the exact content `name` in the `item` row (list of cells) (`item` is actually the row you stored earlier, bad naming :))

What you need is to scan each item to see if the string is contained. So write:

```
if any(name in cell for cell in item):
```

instead

`any` will return `True` as soon as if finds `name` substring in a cell of `item`.
Note that this is a substring match, not a word match. `key` will match a string containing `keyword`. If you want a word match (by splitting words according to blanks):

```
if any(name in cell.split() for cell in item):
```

Comment: @StamKaly exactly what I mean with the `any` part. But you cannot use `==` because it would amount to the `name in item` problem (let me remind you that `item` is the row). The second expression allows to check if the word is in a string (substrings won't match)